# Boost filesystem not found

Tags: boost-filesystem

I get the following error during my PION installation in Oracle Linux 5.5:

```
 Unable to link with the boost filesystem library
```

The curious is that others libraries can be found and there are in the same directory

Can anyone help me on this..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dev package.
The process depends on chosen system/distribution.
In Ubuntu it would be

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem1.49-dev
```